Preferred object in Health Cloud for infusion or injection or any other treatment?
In Health Cloud, there are multiple objects both standard and belonging to managed package which seem to have duplicate purpose.
For example,

HealthCloudGA__EHRProcedure__c
HealthCareProcedure
PatientMedicalProcedure

Which one is preferred to log the event of a patient having infusion or injection or any other treatment?

Just reading the documentation
EhrProcedure__c

This packaged object has a standard object counterpart in the Clinical Data Model. We recommend using the standard object because it’s more closely aligned with FHIR v4.0.

PatientMedicalProcedure appears to be the counterpart - you can see it has basically the same object description which would fit your use-case (patient undergoing a procedure).

Represents detailed information about a healthcare procedure the patient has undergone, is undergoing or will undergo. This object is available in API version 51.0 and later.

HealthCareProcedure isn't duplicating that info - but rather stores information on the procedure code

Represents information related to industry-standard healthcare procedure codes.


if the HealthCareProcedure stores information on the procedure code, why PatientMedicalProcedure  doesn't have lookup or master detail to it?

It's through PatientMedicalProcedureDetail

PatientMedicalProcedureDetail has a lookup to PatientMedicalProcedure but not to HealthCareProcedure  or am I missing anything/

Nope, just me misreading your question. Why are you assuming it needs a lookup if HealthCareProcedure is, as the docs say Represents information related to industry-standard healthcare procedure codes? What's the goal/feature you're thinking to solve? There's other objects (CareInterventionType, CodeSet, Identifier) but I'm not sure what your question is (and full disclosure, not an expert in HC just reading docs).
